# List GitHub Branches Dynamically In Jenkins Jobs

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-groovy

I'm working with jenkins 2.249.3 and active choices plugin - version 2.5.1

I'm trying to create an interactive job that allows users to select a git branch from which they will deploy the product.

I found some nice solutions on how to do that but from some reason I get empty list

the script goes like that:

```
def gitBranches = ("git ls-remote --heads git@github.com:org/repository.git").execute()
```

and then `return gitBranches.text.readLines().collect {  it.split()[1].replaceAll('refs/heads/', '').replaceAll("\\^\\{\\}", '') }`

I think that the git command does not success at all. I verified that when I run the same command from the jenkins server itself it works so I guess I don't understand something regarding the context in which the groovy script is running.

Comment: If it works in Jenkins server but it doesn't elsewhere, could it be that you don't have the ssh key to access the repo in that pc?

Comment: Did you cinsider another plugin - [Git Parameter](https://plugins.jenkins.io/git-parameter/) or [List Git Branches Parameter](https://plugins.jenkins.io/list-git-branches-parameter/) ?

Comment: I found the git parameter less effective in my case since I want to checkout the devOps repository on which the jenkins file resides, and let the user to choose branch from the product repository. For that, I had to checkout **both repositories** in the scm configuration and mention the specific repository on git plugin configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Ok... I got it and indeed it's ssh issue. I'll explain

In my jenkins server there was already ssh private key that was configured for ubuntu user while I needed to configure another key for jenkins user.

I generated a new ssh key and saved it under another name. (id_rsa_2)

Jenkins is running the script in kind of a sandbox/shell that does not load automatically all the keys under .ssh folder (Correct me If I'm saying something stupid). My workaround for that was writing a bash script that runs "ssh-add" command and than launches git ls-remote command.